# Repeating questions based on giving correct answers

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

I am making a web-app that is supposed to help people memorize Japanese kana symbols using [flashcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcard). How it works at the moment is that on each new flashcard, user is presented with one symbol which gets chosen randomly from a pool of X symbols. User than has to recognize that symbol and if he is successful, correct count and total number of tries for that symbol both go up by one. If the user failed to recognize the symbol only the total number of tries goes up by one.

I would like to make the symbols that user had lower success recognizing appear more frequently to make the learning more efficient. Is there a distribution, or a statistical method (using some kind of weight factors or something like that) that is used to do something like this which I could use? I don't even have a clue what to google for.. How do I properly model weight factors based on success rate (percentage)?

Comment: This might be along the lines of what you intend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any standard way to do this.  However given that you have the proportion of correct answers to each symbol you could weight the probability of selection to be inversely proportional to the proportion correct.